# Fetch Feeds from another site

Tags: wordpress

How to fetch rss feeds from another site and show according to month wise, week wise...

I want to accomplish this in wordpress can anyone suggest me how to fetch the feeds. I have url and thats all nothing extra, is there any plugin or widget available? Or can you give an idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use google feed api key for your feed url..

you can google it.. 
https://developers.google.com/feed/
tutorial
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/googleajaxfeed.shtml
its simple.

Comment: can you explain me how to implement this in wordpress because i am newbie in wp.